# can't connecto to Samba Server on NAS

Tags: samba, cifs, nas

I bought a NAS which is SMB and FTP Server. In Summary, FTP works but Samba doesn't.
Here is the topology:

[image]

If I try to connect with nautilus:

```
$ nautilus smb://erlington@192.168.40.10

Unable to initialize DBus connection: The connection is closed
(nautilus:8489): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)

(nautilus:8489): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable to connect to session bus: The connection is closed    
(nautilus:8489): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable to connect to session bus: The connection is closed    
(nautilus:8489): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
(nautilus:8489): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed    
(nautilus:8489): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
No DBus connection available`
```

Using sambaclient:

```
# smbclient -L 192.168.40.10 -U erlington -d 3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface wlan0 ip=192.168.50.46 bcast=192.168.50.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.1.6-Ubuntu).
Enter erlington's password: 
Connecting to 192.168.40.10 at port 445
Connecting to 192.168.40.10 at port 139
Domain=[R] OS=[R] Server=[R]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    luminet         Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       
>Connecting to 192.168.40.10 at port 139
>Domain=[R] OS=[R] Server=[R]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

My `smb.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/samba/smb.conf 

#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   netbios name = erlington

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
    server string = %h server (Samba, Linux Mint)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0 wlan0 

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = no



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

`smbclient` to localhost:

```
$ smbclient -L localhost -U erlington -d 3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.50.19 bcast=192.168.50.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.1.6-Ubuntu).
Enter erlington's password: 
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name localhost<0x20>
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name localhost<0x20>
resolve_wins: WINS server resolution selected and no WINS servers listed.
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name localhost<0x20>
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=74)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x608a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (erlington server (Samba, Linux Mint))
    HP-Color-LaserJet-CM1017 Printer   HP Color LaserJet CM1017
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 at port 139
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=74)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x608a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    ERLINGTON            erlington server (Samba, Linux Mint)
    ROBERT-LUMINET       robert-luminet server (Samba, Ubuntu)

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    MSHOME               LAURA
```

Netstat:

```
$ netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2210            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7530/wineserver 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2211            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7530/wineserver 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8099          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3959/spotify    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6840/smbd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4371          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3959/spotify    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57621           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3959/spotify    
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      933/dnsmasq     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1181/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6821/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1510/ntop       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6840/smbd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3959/spotify    
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      6840/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1181/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      6821/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      6840/smbd
```

I tried with cifs utils

```
cd ~
mkdir server
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.40.10/sharename server -o user=erlington,pass=password
```

The result:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.40.10/sharename server -o user=erlington,pass=password
[sudo] password for erlington: 
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

When I keep trying:

```
umount: it seems the /home/server is mounted multiple times
```

I hope I'm giving enough information and not too much. Sorry if that is the case.

Comment: Is the smb.conf the configuration on the NAS, or on the client?